# What's relationship between dict and attrs in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, orm, metaclass

I'm a beginner of python. I was learning meta-class but I did not quite understand how dictionary store methods and attributes?

```
class ModelMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if name=='Model':
            return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        print('Found model: %s' % name)
        mappings = dict()
        for k, v in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(v, Field):
                print('Found mapping: %s ==> %s' % (k, v))
                mappings[k] = v
        for k in mappings.keys():
            attrs.pop(k)
        attrs['__mappings__'] = mappings
        attrs['__table__'] = name 
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

I assume that attrs can store not only variables but methods. if it was doing so, what's keys and values in this dictionary, attrs?

Comment: Methods are just attributes that are callable. Object attributes are often stored in a dictionary, named `__dict__` (also an attribute, via a mechanism called 'slots').

Comment: If you are a beginner, you can safely ignore metaclasses for a while.

Comment: By the way, abbreviating "attributes" to "attrs" can create confusion because there is a popular Python library called [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attributes of a class are indeed stored in a dictionary. Note that methods are *just attributes too*; they just happen to be callable. Python uses dictionaries in a lot of places; the global namespace of a module is a dictionary too, for example. It is usually the job of the [`object.__getattribute__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) to translate attribute access into a key lookup in the attribute dictionary.

The body of a class statement is executed like a function, and the resulting local namespace (the dictionary produced by calling [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)) is then handed the metaclass to produce the class object. That's what `attrs` is bound to in you example code.

See the [`class` statement reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see [Naming and binding](The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see Naming and binding), using a newly created local namespace and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains mostly function definitions.) **When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved**. A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes **and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary**.

Bold emphasis mine.

You can find more detail in the [*Metaclasses* section of the datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses); quoting the [*Creating the class object* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object):

> Once the class namespace has been populated by executing the class body, the class object is created by calling `metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)`

The namespace dictionary is then attached to the newly-created class object by `type.__new__()`.

The [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) covers this as well, under the *Custom classes* section:

> A class has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object. Class attribute references are translated to lookups in this dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]` (although there are a number of hooks which allow for other means of locating attributes).

You may want to read up on [*descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) as well; methods are created by binding functions found in the class namespace to the instance on which you looked up the method name.